# Equivalence versus Isomorphism of Categories

Tags: ct.category-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can skeleta simplify category theory?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11674/can-skeleta-simplify-category-theory)

When one first learns about categories, one confusing fact is that the nicest notion of two categories being the same is not isomorphism - it is rather equivalence. But it's occurred to me that when two categories are equivalent but not isomorphic, it seems that the only reason why this is so is because one category has multiple copies of the same object.

Could we make a notion of some type of category in which no two different objects are isomorphic? Let's call such a category *succinct*, since I don't know any other term for it (I hope succinct doesn't have another meaning). Then would it be true that any two succinct categories which are equivalent are also isomorphic? And if we have any category, we can form a new succinct category by identifying isomorphic objects. Then the question arises, why don't we just always work with succinct categories? Why, if we're interested in the category of sets, don't we say that any two sets with the same cardinality are not only isomorphic, but are actually the *same* object in the category of sets?

Comment: This seems to be more or less a duplicate of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11674/can-skeleta-simplify-category-theory

Comment: The problem is that categories, as they appear in nature, are not succint/skeletal. 

Comment: I've closed this question, since the answers to the earlier question render it somewhat redundant.

Comment: Sorry, you are right that it is the same. I searched but didn't find it, probably in part because I didn't know the term "skeletal."

Comment: As a side remark, I don't see why having multiple copies of isomorphic objects should be a defect. They naturally arise in many situations. Think e.g. to tangent spaces of a manifold. Also, non trivial categorical constructions may be done on families of isomorphic objects (e.g. tangent bundles, to stay in theme).  


Answer (score 8):

These categories are known as *skeletons*, or *skeletal categories*. Unfortunately, given a category $\mathcal C$, one can not define in general the structure of a category on the class of isomorphic classes of objects of $\mathcal C$ (to see way, try to define the arrows). What one can do is to use the axiom of choice to choose a single object in each isomorphism class, and thus define a skeletal full subcategory of $\mathcal C$ (the *skeleton* of $\mathcal C$).

Identifying isomorphic objects is often an extremely bad idea. The question whether two sets are equal is very different from that of whether they have the same cardinality.

Comment: And choosing which wasteful objects to discard is generally a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

A groupoid is a category where every morphism is an isomorphism. Taking its skeleton throws the baby with the water, as you are left with a category where there are no morphisms between different objects, i.e., a bunch of groups or a diagonal groupoid.

Comment: Not true. Let this groupoid be a group. Then it's already skeletal.

Comment: LOL, you are right, I will edit in a sec

Comment: (My objection is no longer valid now that the answer has been edited).